# Передать динамический массив в функцию

Tags: c, массивы, функции, объявление

Как передать массив в функцию?

```
int main()
{
   int m,n;
   scanf("%d%d", &m,&n);
    int A[m][n], B[m], i, j, z=0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
            if(j){
                if(A[i][j] >= 0 && A[i][j - 1] < 0)
                    z++;
                if(A[i][j] < 0 && A[i][j - 1] >= 0)
                    z++;
            }
        }
        B[i] = z;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нельзя передать динамический массив, можно передать лишь ссылку (точнее указатель) на массив. Хорошо, я, допустим, передал А. Как вы будете знать границы массива?

Comment: В этом то и проблема, я плохо в этом разбираюсь, поэтому и пытаюсь разобраться как написать функцию, но пока не добился никакого результата.

Comment: В какую функцию вы хотите его передавать? в исходнике никакой попытки вызова не видно.

Comment: Я как раз за этим сюда и обратился, ибо не представляю каким образом можно передать этот массив в функцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, допустим, нужна функция вывода одномерного массива. Это можно сделать так:

```
void out(int x[], unsigned size)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%5d ",x[i]);
    puts("");
};

int main()
{
    int A[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    out(A,6);
}
```

или так

```
void out(int *x, unsigned size)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%5d ",x[i]);
    puts("");
};
```

Чтобы сделать так:

```
void out(int x[6])
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        printf("%5d ",x[i]);
    puts("");
};

int main()
{
    int A[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    out(A);
}
```

нужно знать размер массива во время компиляции.

Вот большой кусок из "C. Справочник. Полное описание языка":

---

Если вам необходимо передать в качестве аргумента в функцию массив, соответствующий параметр обычно объявляется следующим образом:

```
тип имя[]
```

Поскольку имена массивов автоматически преобразуются в указатели при их использовании в качестве аргументов функции, эта инструкция эквивалентна объявлению:

```
тип *имя
```

При использовании обозначения массива в объявлении параметров функции любое константное выражение в квадратных скобках (`[]`) игнорируется. В блоке функции имя параметра является переменной-указателем и может быть изменено. Таким образом, функция `addArray()` в примере 7.4 изменяет свои первые два параметра в процессе попарного суммирования элементов в двух массивах.

```
Пример 7.4. Функция addArray()
// addArray() прибавляет каждый элемент второго массива к
// соответствующему элементу первого (т.е., если можно так
// выразиться, выполняет операцию "array1 += array2").
// Аргументы: два массива float и их общая длина.
// Возвращаемое значение: нет.
void addArray( register float a1[ ],
               register const float a2[ ], int len )
{
    register float *end = a1 + len;
    for ( ; a1 < end; ++a1, ++a2 )
        *a1 += *a2;
}
```

Эквивалентным определением функции `addArray()`, использующим иную запись для параметров-массивов, является

```
void addArray( float *a1,
               const float *a2, int len )
{ /* Тело функции такое же, как и ранее. */ }
```

Преимуществом объявления параметров со скобками (`[]`) является то, что читатель исходного текста сразу распознает, что функция обрабатывает аргументы как указатели на массив, а не на единственную переменную данного типа. Однако запись с использованием скобок имеет две особенности при объявления параметров.

- В объявлении параметра (и только в нем) C99 позволяет вам использовать в квадратных скобках любые квалификаторы типов — `const`, `volatile` и `restrict`. Эта возможность позволяет объявлять параметр как имеющий квалифицированный тип указателя.
- Кроме того, в C99 в квадратных скобках можно указать спецификатор класса памяти `static` вместе с целочисленным константным выражением. Этот подход указывает, что количество элементов в массиве в момент вызова функции должно быть по крайней мере равным значению константного выражения.
  Вот пример, в котором объединены обе эти возможности:

  `int func( long array[const static 5] )
  { /* ... */ }`

В определенной здесь функции параметр `array` является константным указателем на `long` и не может быть изменен. Он указывает на первый из как минимум пяти элементов массива.

C99 позволяет также объявлять параметры массива как массивы переменной длины. Чтобы сделать это, заключите неконстантное целочисленное выражение с положительным значением в квадратные скобки. В таком случае этот параметр массива все равно остается указателем на первый элемент массива. Разница заключается в том, что сам массив может иметь переменную длину. В примере 7.5 третий параметр функции `maximum()` представляет собой двумерный массив с переменными измерениями.

```
Пример 7.5. Функция maximum()
// Функция maximum() получает наибольшее значение в
// двумерном массиве значений double.
// Аргументы: количество строк, количество столбцов и матрица.
// Возвращаемое значение: значение наибольшего элемента.
double maximum( int nrows, int ncols, double matrix[nrows][ncols] )
{
    double max = matrix[0][0];
    for ( int r = 0; r < nrows; ++r )
        for ( int c = 0; c < ncols; ++c )
            if ( max < matrix[r][c] )
                max = matrix[r][c];
    return max;
}
```

Параметр `matrix` является указателем на массив с `ncols` элементами.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Можете посмотреть его еще раз :) - он дополнен большой цитатой из книги :)

Answer (score 0):

Правильное название подобных массивов

```
int m,n;
scanf("%d%d", &m,&n);
int A[m][n], B[m], i, j, z=0;
    ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^
```

не динамические массивы, а массивы переменной длины (**Variable Length Array - VLA**).

При этом переменные `m` и `n` должны быть инициализированы до объявлений массивов, и должны быть положительными числами отличными от 0.

Если вы хотите передать эти два массива в некоторую функцию, то объявление параметров функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void f( size_t m, size_t n, int A[m][n], int B[m] );
```

Это объявление эквивалентно следующему объявлению

```
void f( size_t m, size_t n, int ( *A )[n], int *B );
```

Первое объявление просто более самодокументируемое.

То есть параметры функции, объявленные как массивы, неявно преобразуются к типу указателей на их элементы. Поэтому вышеприведенные объявления эквивалентны и определяют одну и ту же функцию. Вы даже можете включить в программу оба этих объявления (которые не являются одновременно определениями), и программа будет нормально компилироваться. Для определения функции вы можете использовать любое из ее объявления. Например

```
void f( size_t m, size_t n, int A[m][n], int B[m] );
void f( size_t m, size_t n, int ( *A )[n], int *B );

void f( size_t m, size_t n, int A[m][n], int B[m] )
{
    /// некоторые предложения функции
}
```

Обратите внимание, что объявление переменной `n` должно предшествовать объявлению параметра `int ( *A )[n]` , или объявления переменных `m` и `n` должны предшествовать объявлениям `int A[m][n]` и `int B[m]`, так как первые используются в объявлениях вторых.